# Showing and hiding previous and next elements in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create sort of a carousel that works in a way of hiding and showing the images upon clicking the next and previous buttons. I have grouped my images in a table and gave the li elements a class of 'li'. I have four images, and when I load the page the first image by default is the only one that displays. When I click the next button it jumps from the first image to the fourth. After that, when i press the previous button, it will then show images one, two, and three.

How do i get it to display them in order? Below is my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/aj4tpu1z/

```
var prev = $('.prev');
var next = $('.next');

    $('.li').each(function() {
        var left = $(this).prev();
        var right = $(this).next();

        next.on('click', function(){    
            left.hide();
            right.show();
        });

        prev.on('click', function(){
            left.show();
            right.hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you post html too? Perhaps a full code-snippet/jsfiddle example we can easily view

Comment: You might want to save the array of `li` elements to a variable, and take the `click` event listeners out of the `.each`. Then you can use the click events to determine which index of the array to show, and hide the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your `.next` and `.prev` get four (*as many images*) click handlers, one for each image (*since you apply it in a loop*). So when you click, all four are executed, but the last is for the fourth element so that is what stays at the end.

You need to calculate the next/prev at the moment of the click. So it is best to add a class to the current image and also use that to style it.

```js
var prev = $('.prev');
var next = $('.next');
var images = $('.images li');

function showImage( node ){
  node.addClass('active') // show specified node
      .siblings().removeClass('active'); // hide previously active node
}

prev.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // avoid scrolling to top or following the link
  
  var previousNode = images.filter('.active').prev();
  showImage(previousNode);
});
next.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // avoid scrolling to top or following the link
  
  var nextNode = images.filter('.active').next();
  showImage(nextNode);
});

$('.images li:first').addClass('active');
```

```css
.images li{display:none;}
.images li.active{display:initial}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="prev">&#8592;</a>
<a href="#" class="next">&#8594;</a>


<div class="images">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200?text=1" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200?text=2" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200?text=3" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200?text=4" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You had a couple of things going on, including that the `next` and `prev` click handlers were inside the `.li` class' `.each()` loop.

Here's a working example (the images have been replaced with numbers, since they won't load anyway):

```js
var prev = $('.prev');
var next = $('.next');
var num = 0;

$('.li').hide();
$('.li').eq(0).show();

next.on('click', function() {
  $('.li').hide();
  num++;
  if (num > 3) {
    num = 0;
  }
  $('.li').eq(num).show();
});

prev.on('click', function() {
  $('.li').hide();
  num--;
  if (num < 0) {
    num = 3;
  }
  $('.li').eq(num).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="prev">&#8592;</a>
<a href="#" class="next">&#8594;</a>


<div class="images">
  <ul>
    <li class="li">(Img 1)</li>
    <li class="li">(Img 2)</li>
    <li class="li">(Img 3)</li>
    <li class="li">(Img 4)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This example assumes you want to be able to go from slide 4 to slide 1 and vice versa; if you don't, let me know and I can change the code.

Comment: Hi, can you add animation for left and right.? just like google login page has.That would be more beautiful.

Comment: Sure, you could do that.

Comment: That would be a separate question than this one. Ask it as [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and be sure to include anything that you've already tried in the description.